# How to convert pubsub message to string or json? I am trying to convert pubsub message to string but the result shows up some unwanted characters

Tags: c#, json, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

```
Task startTask = subscriber.StartAsync((PubsubMessage message, CancellationToken cancel) =>
            {
                //string text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Data.ToArray());
               
                var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Data.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine($"Message {message.MessageId}: {data}");
                Interlocked.Increment(ref messageCount);
                return Task.FromResult(true ? SubscriberClient.Reply.Ack : SubscriberClient.Reply.Nack);
```

Below is the data showing up when I do the conversion

"??♠►????☺*??♠►????☺2↕    ?I►??L@◄☻MP?L?'@:↕      ?I►??L☻MP?L?'@E??J♦►☻↑☻

Comment: Do you know what the expected message data should look like? If yes could you please extend your question?

Comment: What do you expect? If you expect binary data, it seems consistent.